# Octave : Index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab, octave

I wrote the following function in a file named conditionals.m:

```
function result = conditionals(category, feature)

result=5;

end
```

I call this function from Octave's command line:

```
v=conditionals(3,4)
```

I get the following error:

```
error : A(I) : Index exceeds matrix dimension.
```

Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

The error:

> error : A(I) : Index exceeds matrix dimension.

Indicates that octave thinks that `conditionals` is a matrix, not a function.

Octave probably doesn't know that `conditionals` is a function - and instead it's treating it as a matrix.

Have you checked to see if the function is in Octave's search path?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
octave> function result = conditionals (category, feature)
>   result = 5;
> endfunction
octave> v = conditionals (3, 4)
v =  5
```

The error suggests that you have a variable with the same name as the function. Type `whos` at the Octave prompt to see a list of defined variables. If you see one named `conditionals`, remove it with `clear conditionals`

Also, if conditionals is a `conditionals.m` file, make sure it's on the function search path. Run `path` at the Octave prompt to see the function search path. Run `which  conditionals` at the command prompt to see where the function is located.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well and it can happen on any command, regardless of the command name. When I run the `PS1(">>");` to change the command prompt in Ovtave, I got the same error.

> octave-3.2.3.exe:9> PS1(">>");
>
> error: A(I): Index exceeds matrix dimension.

As others also mentioned, this error fires when there is a parameter with the same command name. It happens when we mistakenly enter the command with wrong syntax and hence, octave run the command and produce a variable with your command name that overload the internal command.

You can verify this status by `who` command. If you can see the same variable name as your command here, you have to remove it. Use `clear variable_name` to remove the variable.

Here is my output for PS1 command.

[image]

Hope it helps.